# Issue with Gallery

Tags: android

I am extending Gallery class & displaying scrollable images in a horizontal manner.
I am displaying only on the landscape mode.

For displaying the images , I am using BaseAdapter , since I need to place text & icon over the images.

I am displaying the no of images based on a condition which is set.

I want to put the following conditions.

i> If the no of image to be displayed is 1 , I'll only show a single image on the middle of the screen & there should not be any scrolling.

ii> If the no of images to be displayed is 2 , then both the images should be shown side by side(horizontal) & without any scrolling.

iii> Only if the no  of images is equal to or greater than 3 , then images should be displayed in the horizontal manner & scrollable.

How can I handle all the above cases using a single layout xml & by handling the conditions source code.

Kindly provide me your inputs/sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Warm Regards,

CB

Answer (score 1):

well for showing the text and the image you will need to create a custom adapter override the getView method and a custom layout (a linear layout with vertical orientation containing a textView and an ImageView) inside the getView. You can find a lot of examples of doing that on google, its pretty simple.(there is the gallery example on the android developers page that explains this). [Hello Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

For your conditions you can probably make something like this in the adapter constructor or the actual creation of the adapter in the activity. i think by default it wont be scrollable for 1 item, but for 2 it will be since the gallery centers the selected item... which is pretty lame. and for 3 or more it will work as intended (show a scrollable horizontal list of items).

Hope this helps.